# display search result as a area in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I search for a post code or general area, google map gives a area for that post code or general area (red bold border).

How to implement it using google map api v3? I have read throurgh it but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently offered in the API.